# How to make text break into new line if it's longer than container

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic2, angular2-template

I have a line of text on an ion-card that will have a varying length every time. 
I need to be able to tell when the text has reached the end of the card (on both ios and android - which can have an even smaller screen) so I can break it into a new line.

this is what the card looks like:

```
<ion-card>
       <ion-item>

          <p><i>On:</i><span id="showName">{{event.showName}}</span></p>

            <p><i>At:</i><span id="venueName">{{event.venue}}</span></p>

        </ion-item> 
<ion-card>
```

**UPDATE**
I tried the first answer suggestion and added the break-word overflow wrap to css but it didn't work. I still need hel.

```
#showName{
    display: inline;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    font-size:  2rem; 
    font-weight: 800;
    word-spacing: -2px

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col col-12>
      <ion-item>
        <p><i>On:</i><span id="showName">{{event.showName}}</span></p>
        <p><i>At:</i><span id="venueName">{{event.venue}}</span></p>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

inside "ion-card" tag, put this code and try to run. It will restrict your text to that particular area only.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use css, for display purpouses:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap

> overflow-wrap: break-word;

Answer (score 1):

Your content will be automatically wrapped into an `ion-label`. This element have default css is: `white-space: nowrap`. You need to overide it:

```
.label{
    white-space: normal !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ionic have a CSS utility `text-wrap`: https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-utilities/

Thus:

```
<ion-card>
  <ion-item>
    <p text-wrap><i>On:</i><span id="showName">{{event.showName}}</span></p>
    <p text-wrap><i>At:</i><span id="venueName">{{event.venue}}</span></p>
  </ion-item> 
<ion-card>
```